# EJBCA 'Ubuntu quick start' fails to deploy on JBoss

Tags: jboss, ejbca

I followed quick start steps described in EJBCA documentation (http://www.ejbca.org/docs/installation.html)

'ant deploy' eventually failed with the following error

```
...
...
    set-paths-not-jboss7:

set-paths:

jee:deployServicesJBoss5:

jee:assert-runJBoss7:
     [echo] Checking if JBoss 7 is up and running...
     [exec] Result: 1

BUILD FAILED
/home/pa/ejbca-setup/ejbca_ce_6_0_3/build.xml:635: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/pa/ejbca-setup/ejbca_ce_6_0_3/bin/jboss.xml:380: The requested action requires that JBoss 7 is up and running.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was that JBoss wasn't starting.  The documentation did point out that if 'ant deploy' fails, most likely caused is JBoss not running.

Since JBoss did not show any error, I *thought* it was up, however upon second look I understood that it was stuck in 'starting' state.  There were no errors in log files.  My Java version was 8.  Installing Java 7 fixed the problem.  Be sure to recompile EJBCA after switching Java.